# What can I do to improve a business-oriented network that only has access to 3 6Mb/1.5Mb lines with 15-30 clients?

Tags: networking, wifi

I work at an e-commerce based business in a 16k warehouse. The only available ISP solution is AT&T, with each 6Mb/1.5Mb line costing $50 and fiber optic being an option for $800/mo at 20Mb/20Mb.

Around 15 clients are wired throughout the offices, and another 10 or so exist wirelessly.

I know very little about the stack as it was setup before I arrived, but I am very aware of the real problem we have: it's slow. I don't know if it is download (SpeedTest shows 18Mb down), upload (I was told you can only combine download speeds, not uploading speeds, so SpeedTest shows 1.5Mb) or latency (SpeedTest does not show anything abnormal).

We are using a PepLink to load balance the 3 lines into one solution, but I fear it may be set up incorrectly. I don't know how else to explain why the lag that exists is randomly occurring.

What are common solutions here?

Answer (score 1):

[PfSense](https://www.pfsense.org/) is capable to do what you want - it doing load-balancing on a Multi-WAN connection. The only thing you may be need **bonding** on ISP side to get combine Up/Down traffic. If you ISP won't to do bonding, you can try 3rd party provider such as [Mushroom Networks](https://www.mushroomnetworks.com/product/broadband-bonding-service)

To protect traffic from abuse by employees, you can use on [PfSense](https://www.pfsense.org/) proxy with authentication. This way any "home calling" software (that spread around this days) on workstations will be blocked except those connections you may allow. Traffic shaping is also good to go to prevent youtube, torrents and other banwide hungry software.

P.S.
I tried also spare wireless providers such as Verison, t-mobile, but they are expensive(not as fiber,but...) and their traffic allotted, besides of awful equipment that need to be physically reinserted(any reset sequences over USB won't work) in case of it got stack, but there is areas where businesses doesn't have other choices and use them also as spare channel